# SendMessage from a Delphi app to a Java app RICHEDIT50W control

Tags: java, delphi, winapi, sendmessage

Does anyone know how to send a text from a Delphi app to a java app RICHEDIT50W control? I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
oPinWindowHandle := FindWindow(nil, 'My Caption');
oRichEditControl := FindWindowEx(oPinWindowHandle, 0, 'RICHEDIT50W', nil);
SendMessage(oRichEditControl, WM_SETTEXT, 0, LongInt(PChar(msg)));
```

Both oRichEditControl and oPinWindowHandle have a valid handle.

**EDIT**

SendMessage is working fine. It returns 1. Maybe the app is blocking messages ou even handle its own message. Is there any way to find which messages the app accepts?

Comment: first of all double check that the hwnd is correct with Spy++

Comment: does the call to SendMessage return an error? When a message is blocked by UIPI
the last error, retrieved with GetLastError, is set to 5 (access denied).

Comment: @Rafael which is the value returned by the `SendMessage` function (must be 1 or true if works ok)?

Comment: SendMessage does not return any error. It seems to me that the WM_SETTEXT is not the right message to be sent.

Comment: I'm just curious: does this way to pass the text really work between processes? I would expect that the java app cannot access the memory of the Delphi application (where the `PChar` is pointing at).

Comment: what value does SendMessage return?

Comment: @smasher It works fine. The system marshals the text.

Comment: WM_SETTEXT is the correct message, test against windows write.exe which hosts a RICHEDIT50W, if your code works then the java app must be implementing special text handling for that window

Comment: Humm, maybe the java app is blocking messages from another app .. is it possible? It works fine on write.exe.

Comment: SendMessage is returning 1 .. I am not able to find why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the app was blocking some messages, and then I came across to this thread:

[Sending an application keystrokes with “SendMessage”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641869/sending-an-application-keystrokes-with-sendmessage-vb-net)

Which helped me a lot to bypass the issue.